# How to write ternary operator for an errorText in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to write a ternary operator for an errorText.

This is the code that I want to write. It's in the InputDecoration of TextFormField widget.

```
String userPassword = '';
String passwordError = 'Password must be at least 7 characters long.';
errorText: userPassword.isEmpty ? passwordError : null;
```

However it doesn't work because userPassword is Invalid constant value. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It is working fine for me, probably your TextField has a "const" keyword before it or maybe you have written "const" before InputDecoration.

Comment: It is not possible to reproduce the error from current snippet. You can check more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)